# Mysql subquery much faster than join

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I have the following queries which both return the same result and row count:

```
select * from (
               select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(network_time) * 1000 as epoch_network_datetime, 
                      hbrl.business_rule_id, 
                      display_advertiser_id, 
                      hbrl.campaign_id, 
                      truncate(sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_spend_network, 0))/100000.0, 2) as demand_ad_spend_network, 
                      sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_view, 0)) as demand_ad_view, 
                      sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_click, 0)) as demand_ad_click, 
                      truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_view) = 0 then 0 else 100*sum(hbrl.ad_click)/sum(hbrl.ad_view) end, 0), 2) as ctr_percent, 
                      truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_view) = 0 then 0 else sum(hbrl.ad_spend_network)/100.0/sum(hbrl.ad_view) end, 0), 2) as ecpm,
                      truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_click) = 0 then 0 else sum(hbrl.ad_spend_network)/100000.0/sum(hbrl.ad_click) end, 0), 2) as ecpc 
               from hourly_business_rule_level hbrl
               where (publisher_network_id = 31534) 
               and network_time between str_to_date('2017-08-13 17:00:00.000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') and str_to_date('2017-08-14 16:59:59.999000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') 
               and (network_time IS NOT NULL and display_advertiser_id > 0)
               group by network_time, hbrl.campaign_id, hbrl.business_rule_id
               having demand_ad_spend_network > 0
               OR demand_ad_view > 0
               OR demand_ad_click > 0
               OR ctr_percent > 0
               OR ecpm > 0
               OR ecpc > 0
               order by epoch_network_datetime) as atb
       left join dim_demand demand on atb.display_advertiser_id = demand.advertiser_dsp_id 
       and atb.campaign_id = demand.campaign_id 
       and atb.business_rule_id = demand.business_rule_id
```

ran explain extended, and these are the results:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys                                                                 | key     | key_len | ref             | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                 | ALL  | NULL                                                                          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 1451739 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | demand                     | ref  | PRIMARY,join_index                                                            | PRIMARY | 4       | atb.campaign_id |       1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | hourly_business_rule_level | ALL  | _hourly_business_rule_level_supply_idx,_hourly_business_rule_level_demand_idx | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 1494447 |    97.14 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

and the other is:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(network_time) * 1000 as epoch_network_datetime, 
       hbrl.business_rule_id, 
       display_advertiser_id, 
       hbrl.campaign_id, 
       truncate(sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_spend_network, 0))/100000.0, 2) as demand_ad_spend_network, 
       sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_view, 0)) as demand_ad_view, 
       sum(coalesce(hbrl.ad_click, 0)) as demand_ad_click, 
       truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_view) = 0 then 0 else 100*sum(hbrl.ad_click)/sum(hbrl.ad_view) end, 0), 2) as ctr_percent, 
       truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_view) = 0 then 0 else sum(hbrl.ad_spend_network)/100.0/sum(hbrl.ad_view) end, 0), 2) as ecpm, 
       truncate(coalesce(case when sum(hbrl.ad_click) = 0 then 0 else sum(hbrl.ad_spend_network)/100000.0/sum(hbrl.ad_click) end, 0), 2) as ecpc 
from hourly_business_rule_level hbrl
join dim_demand demand on hbrl.display_advertiser_id = demand.advertiser_dsp_id 
and hbrl.campaign_id = demand.campaign_id 
and hbrl.business_rule_id = demand.business_rule_id 
where (publisher_network_id = 31534) 
and network_time between str_to_date('2017-08-13 17:00:00.000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') and str_to_date('2017-08-14 16:59:59.999000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') 
and (network_time IS NOT NULL and display_advertiser_id > 0)
group by network_time, hbrl.campaign_id, hbrl.business_rule_id
having demand_ad_spend_network > 0
OR demand_ad_view > 0
OR demand_ad_click > 0 
OR ctr_percent > 0
OR ecpm > 0
OR ecpc > 0
order by epoch_network_datetime;
```

and these are the results for the second query:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys                                                                 | key     | key_len | ref                                                           | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hourly_business_rule_level | ALL  | _hourly_business_rule_level_supply_idx,_hourly_business_rule_level_demand_idx | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                          | 1494447 |    97.14 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | demand                     | ref  | PRIMARY,join_index                                                            | PRIMARY | 4       | my6sense_datawarehouse.hourly_business_rule_level.campaign_id |       1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

the first one takes about 2 seconds while the second one takes over 2 minutes!

why is the second query taking so long? 
what am I missing here?

thanks.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN EXTENDED on these queries, and add the resulting plan info to your question.

Comment: added the explain extended results for both queries.

Comment: How many rows in the output?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Your question isn't even on-topic without one. There is a reason why. Especially indexes & constraints and table sizes/statistics. Read re (logical & physical) query optimization in general & in your product specifically for basic principles. PS ORDER BY has no meaning in a subquery without LIMIT. Tables are unordered. You might happen to get the answer you want with a pariticular implementation. That can be a reason for performance differences, since your 1st query isn't necessarily doing what it needs to for the right answer although likely it happens to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery whenever the subquery significantly shrinks the number of rows before - ANY JOIN - always to reinforce Rick James Plan B.
To reinforce Rick & Paul's answer which you have already documented.  The answers by Rick and Paul deserve Acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is the number of rows that have to be joined with the second table.

The GROUP BY clause and the HAVING clause will limit the number of rows returned from your subquery.
Only those rows will be used for the join.

Without the subquery only the WHERE clause is limiting the number of rows for the JOIN.
The JOIN is done before the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are processed.
Depending on group size and the selectivity of the HAVING conditions there would be much more rows that need to be joined.

Consider the following simplified example:

We have a table `users` with 1000 entries and the columns `id`, `email`.

```
create table users(
    id smallint auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(50) unique
);
```

Then we have a (huge) log table `user_actions` with 1,000,000 entries and the columns `id`, `user_id`, `timestamp`, `action`

```
create table user_actions(
    id mediumint auto_increment primary key,
    user_id smallint not null,
    timestamp timestamp,
    action varchar(50),
    index (timestamp, user_id)
);
```

The task is to find all users who have at least 900 entries in the log table since 2017-02-01.

#### The subquery solution:

```
select a.user_id, a.cnt, u.email
from (
    select a.user_id, count(*) as cnt
    from user_actions a
    where a.timestamp >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
    group by a.user_id
    having cnt >= 900
) a
left join users u on u.id = a.user_id
```

The subquery returns 135 rows (users). Only those rows will be joined with the `users` table.
The subquery runs in about 0.375 seconds. The time needed for the join is almost zero, so the full query runs in about 0.375 seconds.

#### Solution without subquery:

```
select a.user_id, count(*) as cnt, u.email
from user_actions a
left join users u on u.id = a.user_id
where a.timestamp >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
group by a.user_id
having cnt >= 900
```

The WHERE condition filters the table to 866,081 rows.
The JOIN has to be done for all those 866K rows.
After the JOIN the GROUP BY and the HAVING clauses are processed and limit the result to 135 rows.
This query needs about 0.815 seconds.

So you can already see, that a subquery can improve the performance.

But let's make things worse and drop the primary key in the `users` table.
This way we have no index which can be used for the JOIN.
Now the first query runs in 0.455 seconds. The second query needs 40 seconds - almost **100 times slower**.

#### Notes

It's difficult to say if the same applies to your case. Reasons are:

- Your queries are quite complex and far away from from beeing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- I don't see anything beeng selected from the `demand` table - So it's unclear why you are joining it at all.
- You use a LEFT JOIN in one query and an INNER JOIN in another one.
- The relation between the two tables is unclear.
- No information about indexes. You should provide the CREATE statements (`SHOW CREATE table_name`).

#### Test setup

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users(
    id smallint auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(50) unique
)
    select seq as id, rand(1) as email
    from seq_1_to_1000
;


drop table if exists user_actions;
create table user_actions(
    id mediumint auto_increment primary key,
    user_id smallint not null,
    timestamp timestamp,
    action varchar(50),
    index (timestamp, user_id)
)
    select seq as id
        , floor(rand(2)*1000)+1 as user_id
        #, '2017-01-01 00:00:00' + interval seq*20 second as timestamp
        , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00') + seq*20) as timestamp
        , rand(3) as action
    from seq_1_to_1000000
;
```

MariaDB 10.0.19 with sequence plugin.

Comment: actually I was expecting MySql query optimizer to do better than myself restructuring the query

Answer (score 1):

The queries are different.  One says `JOIN`, the other says `LEFT JOIN`.  You are not using `demand`, so the join is probably useless.  However, in the case of `JOIN`, you are filtering out advertisers that are not in `dim_demand`; it that the intent?

But that does not address the question.

The `EXPLAINs` estimate that there are 1.5M rows in `hbrl`.  But how many show up in the result?  I would guess it is a lot fewer.  From this, I can answer your question.

Consider these two:

```
SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT ... FROM a
                      GROUP BY or HAVING or LIMIT ) x
           JOIN b

SELECT ... FROM a
           JOIN b
           GROUP BY or HAVING or LIMIT
```

The first will decrease the number of rows that need to join to `b`; the second will need to do a full 1.5M joins.  I suspect that the time taken to do the `JOIN` (be it `LEFT` or not) is where the difference is.

Plan A:  Remove `demand` from the query.

Plan B:  Use a subquery whenever the subquery significantly shrinks the number of rows *before* the `JOIN`.

Indexing (may speed up *both* variants):

```
INDEX(publisher_network_id, network_time)
```

and get rid of this as being useless (since the `between` will fail anyway for `NULL`):

```
and network_time IS NOT NULL
```

Side note:  I recommend simplifying and fixing this

```
and  network_time
   between str_to_date('2017-08-13 17:00:00.000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f')
       AND str_to_date('2017-08-14 16:59:59.999000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f')
```

to

```
and network_time >= '2017-08-13 17:00:00
and network_time  < '2017-08-13 17:00:00 + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Comment: actually I was expecting MySql query optimizer to do better than myself restructuring the query

Comment: Some of my recommendations actually change the effect of the query -- hopefully for the better.  An optimizer cannot do that.  For example, Did you deliberately want to exclude 999 microseconds from the `BETWEEN`?  My version gives you exactly one day.

Comment: @AviadSharfshtein - Alas, the Optimizer has a very limited focus.  Date functions could use a lot of optimization, but we have to do it by hand.